# vlookup multiple values and sum them against one reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet with all unique ID's and I'd need to run a vlookup against that ID in sheet2.

Sheet 2 looks like below:

```
 ID:     NUMBERS:
  A         488
  A         980
  A         32
  B         693
  C         78
  C         45
```

IF A is found multiple times in sheet2, sum all values from NUMBERS column with reference to A and return in front of A in sheet1.

I am not sure if index(match) would be able to do this because I'd need sums in the end against a single reference not multiple times pull multiple values.

Please suggest a workaround. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I understand your question right, bit this looks like a case for SUMIF instead. Maybe you should add the desired output and what you've tried this far.

Answer (score 3):

Use `SUMIF()` formula to achieve your desired result.

```
=SUMIF(Sheet2!A:A,A2,Sheet2!B:B)
```

[image]

Comment: Very clever, you don't need to retrieve the individual **A**'s, only the sum.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pivot table as below. First select data and destination sheet as shown below. Here data is in Sheet 2 and summary will be populated in Sheet 1.

[image]

Once done then Pivot Menu will appear. Put field `ID` in "Rows" and `Numbers` in "Values" as shown in the image below.

[image]